# Why I cannot extract file with Python

Tags: python, extract, python-zipfile

I don't understand why I cannot extract file and why Python print **KeyError: There is no item named eurofxref.zip in the archive** lang interpreter see file as **eurofxref.csv**

```
import os
import zipfile
from file_from_web_class import FileFromWeb

if __name__ == "__main__":
url = "https://www.ecb.europa.eu/stats/eurofxref/eurofxref.zip"
dir = point_file_from_cwd("temp", "eurofxref.zip")

with FileFromWeb(url, dir) as f:
    with zipfile.ZipFile(f.temp_file, "r") as z:
        path = point_from_cwd("temp")
        a_file = z.namelist()[0]
        print(a_file) #? eurofxref.csv
        os.chdir(path) 
        z.extract("eurofxref.zip", '.', None) #? I don't understand.
```

More details:

```
import os
import zipfile
import requests

class FileFromWeb:


def __init__(self, url, temp_file):
    self.url = url
    self.temp_file = temp_file


def __enter__(self):
    response = requests.get(self.url)
    with open(self.temp_file, "wb") as reading_file:
        reading_file.write(response.content)
    return self


def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_val, exc_tb):
    pass
```

Method on **main.py** file:

```
def point_from_cwd(rel_path):
    defined_path = os.getcwd() + "\\" + rel_path 
    print("You want point dir: ", os.getcwd() + "\\" + rel_path)
    return defined_path

def point_file_from_cwd(rel_path, file_name):
    defined_path = os.getcwd() + "\\" + rel_path + "\\" + file_name 
    print("You want point file in dir: ", os.getcwd() + "\\" + rel_path +  "\\" + file_name)
    return defined_path
```

Comment: Is this you complete code? If not, please, provide the entire code.

Comment: I add complete code.

Comment: Please provide a complete [mre] in future questions. The code you put into your question should be in a _single_ copy/paste area, should include imports and data needed to run it; any editing needed will reduce your chances of getting anyone to run your code to see what's going wrong, i.e. putting coherent code into your question __helps you get an answer__. If you're not sure about your code then try it out for yourself: copy the code from your question into a file and try to run it; edit the code+question until that works.

Answer (score 2):

KeyError is a self-explanatory exception and it basically says "there is no item named eurofxref.zip **in** the archive" so probably you are trying to extract eurofxref.**csv** but providing wrong item.

It should be fine when you change this line if I understand your question with given details:

```
z.extract("eurofxref.zip", '.', None) #? I don't understand.
```

as:

```
z.extract("eurofxref.csv", '.', None) #? I don't understand.
```

Answer (score 0):

[ZipFile.extract](https://docs.python.org/3/library/zipfile.html#zipfile.ZipFile.extract) extracts only specified member from the archive. Try:

```
z.extract("eurofxref.csv", '.', None)
```

or:

```
z.extractall()
```

Comment: It works, I made a minor mistake:
    os.chdir(path)
     z.extract(a_file, '.', None)